# Users - remove 'send password' checkbox

Tags: users, configuration

Is there a recommended method for removing the 'Send password' checkbox when managing users in WordPress admin? Or alternatively a way of alterting users to changes that doesn't involve mailing the password in plain text?

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few ideas how to deal with the **neutralization** of the *Send Password* part on the  `/wp-admin/user-new.php` page:

[image: send pass]

### Idea 1:

We can overwrite the [`wp_new_user_notification()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1569) function, because it's [*pluggable*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions):

Try for example:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_new_user_notification' ) ):

function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass = '') {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

        // The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
        // we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your site %s:'), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user->user_email) . "\r\n";

        @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), $blogname), $message);

        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
                return;

        // Let's remove this user notification part:  

        /* 
        $message  = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

        wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);
        */
endif;
```

if you don't want to notify the user, regardless of the *Send Password* settings.

Here we just removed the code that sends a notification mail to the user.

### Idea 2:

Let's try to remove the *Send Password* settings by hijacking the `show_password_fields` filter:

```
add_action( 'load-user-new.php', function(){
   add_filter( 'show_password_fields', function( $show ){
?>
        <tr class="form-field form-required">
                <th scope="row"><label for="pass1"><?php _e('Password'); ?> <span class="description"><?php /* translators: password input field */_e('(required)'); ?></span></label></th>
                <td>
                        <input class="hidden" value=" " /><!-- #24364 workaround -->
                        <input name="pass1" type="password" id="pass1" autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form-field form-required">
                <th scope="row"><label for="pass2"><?php _e('Repeat Password'); ?> <span class="description"><?php /* translators: password input field */_e('(required)'); ?></span></label></th>
                <td>
                <input name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" autocomplete="off" />
                <br />
                <div id="pass-strength-result"><?php _e('Strength indicator'); ?></div>
                <p class="description indicator-hint"><?php _e('Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers, and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).'); ?></p>
                </td>
        </tr>
<?php
        return FALSE;
    });
});
```

### Idea 3:

We can try to hide it with CSS, for example:

```
add_action( 'load-user-new.php', function(){
    add_action( 'admin_head', function(){
        ?><style>#createuser .form-table tr:nth-of-type(9){ display:none; }</style><?php
    });
});
```

if you don't have any extra user fields, otherwise we might have to adjust the `tr:nth-of-type(9)` part.

### Idea 4:

Use javascript to remove or disable it.

### Idea 5:

You can also try to unset the `$_POST['send_password']` part on submit, before it goes into the `wp_new_user_notification` function:

```
wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, 
                          isset( $_POST['send_password'] ) ? wp_unslash( $pass1 )  : '' );
```

### Idea 6:

This one is theoretical and just for fun:

Use *[output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)* on the `/wp-admin/user-new.php` page and replace the unwanted HTML blocks ;-)

Comment: This was really helpful, I've gone with a combination of 1 and 4 - thanks!

Comment: Also `tr.pw-weak + tr {display: none;}` if you just need to hide it.